# What's the use case for the cookie in android.os.Trace#beginAsyncSection

Tags: android

This is the signature of `android.os.Trace#beginAsyncSection`

```
public static void beginAsyncSection (String methodName, 
                int cookie)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Trace#beginAsyncSection(java.lang.String,%20int)

I understand that the same name and cookie must be used to end it, but what's the purpose of `cookie`? What's the use case for calling this or `endAsyncSection` with the same method name, but a different `cookie`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a unique identifier for distinguishing simultaneous events. Imagine that You have multiple `*AsyncSection` instances of the same method name. The cookie connects `begin` with `end` in each pair. The answer for the last question - You have to call `endAsyncSection` with a cookie used in one of `beginAsyncSection`.